# Laravel Collective Form not showing up even when CSS is added

Tags: laravel, forms, laravelcollective

So I have this issue when I make a form in my project that it shows up in my plain HTML file in Inspector, but it does not show up on my page.

[image: Screenshot of the page.]

I have several forms in my project that use the Laravel Collective version of a form. I do not have the issue there even though I use the same kind of syntax. I only do not use a select form there.

Below is a sample of the code:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductsController@filter', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

{{ Form::select('filteredProduct', [
       'laundry' => 'Wasmachine',
       'dryer' => 'Droger',
   ], null, ['placeholder' => 'Kies een categorie van het apparaat.' ,'class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{Form::submit('Submit de filter.', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Notice that the submit button is rendered, but the select field is not displayed...

Do you guys have any idea on how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Regards,

Frank.

Comment: Changing the method to GET, which it should be, does not resolve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: The only difference I see with a working select in my own local project is that you have a trailing comma `['laundry' => 'Wasmachine','dryer' => 'Droger',]`, try changing it to this: `['laundry' => 'Wasmachine','dryer' => 'Droger']`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either.

Comment: Which Laravel version?

Comment: Nothing stands out as wrong in the Form code, and it looks like the html is being rendered correctly. This seems like it might be an issue with either a missing css class, or other css interfering with the display here?

Comment: Laravel 5.7.3. Yeah could be the CSS but seems so unlikely since I added CSS to the select Form as well. Not shown in above code:

`{{ Form::select('filteredProduct', [
                        'laundry' => 'Wasmachine',
                        'dryer' => 'Droger'
                        ], null, ['placeholder' => 'Kies een categorie van het apparaat.' ,'class' => 'form-control form-group']) }}`

Answer (score 0):

What happen if you double exclamation in your code like this:

```
{!! Form::select('filteredProduct', [
   'laundry' => 'Wasmachine',
   'dryer' => 'Droger',   ], null, ['placeholder' => 'Kies een categorie van het apparaat.' ,'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```